# React Native Can't find variable: window"

Tags: react-native

Attempting to port a react web project over to native I'm getting the following:

> React Native Can't find variable: window"

This is most likely due to me requiring react and attempting to give it global scope with `window.React = require('react-native');`.

What's curious is the project runs fine if I enable debugging with chrome.

If the above is incorrect how do I set a global scope with react native ?

Comment: It's not a browser so there is no `window`. I'm wondering exact what you're trying to do here...

Comment: This can be closed now. Window does get defined from react  native however it seems to do it a tad too late. If in doubt use 'global' instead of window.

Comment: cool well just mark your own question as "answered" - that's as good as closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React needs to be initialised before the window object can be accessed. Regardless of this in general global is preferred(which is what you would use when developing in node).

Answer (score 0):

downgrade react-native to version 0.55.4 will save your time

ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20015